# Simulate Defensepro AMS With Defense4all

Tags: opendaylight, defense4all

how i can simulate Attack Mitigation Systems (AMSs)  with value Radware DefensePro in defense4all ?
i run Opendaylight and defense4all but can not config pane ams in defense4all. 
please help me